# VB.NET Call PL/SQL Procedure

Tags: vb.net, string, plsql, return-value

So I'm calling the below pl/sql statement from a vb.net function. The results are added to a ListBox regardless of whether there is an exception or not. I keep getting the following error when I use the function `ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small` I've tried rewriting the pl/sql statement and the vb.net statement but I just can't seem to find a way to avoid this error. Any advice??

```
create or replace function GET_CUST_STRING_FROM_DB(pcustid number)
return varchar2 as
vcustid number;
vcustname varchar2(100);
vcuststatus varchar2(100);
vcustsales number;

begin

  select custid, custname, status, sales_ytd into vcustid, vcustname, vcuststatus, vcustsales from customer where custid = pcustid;

  return 'Custid: '||vcustid||' Name: '||vcustname||' Status: '||vcuststatus||' SalesYTD: '||vcustsales;
exception
  when NO_DATA_FOUND then
    raise_application_error(-20021, 'Error: Customer ID not found');
  when others then
    raise_application_error(-20000, SQLERRM);
end;
```

The above function is being called by the following vb.net function

```
Private Sub GetCustString(custID As Integer)
        Dim connOracle As Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection
        Dim cmd As New Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleCommand
        Dim param As Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleParameter
        Dim vOutcome As String

        param = New Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleParameter
        param.ParameterName = "vreturn"
        param.DbType = DbType.String
        param.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue
        cmd.Parameters.Add(param)

        param = New Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleParameter
        param.ParameterName = "pcustid"
        param.DbType = DbType.Int64
        param.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input
        param.Value = custID
        cmd.Parameters.Add(param)

        connOracle = CreateConnection()
        lsDisplay.Items.Add("Getting details for custID: " & custID)

        Try
            connOracle.Open()
            cmd.Connection = connOracle
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            cmd.CommandText = "GET_CUST_STRING_FROM_DB"
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            vOutcome = cmd.Parameters.Item("pReturn").Value.ToString
            connOracle.Close()
            lsDisplay.Items.Add(vOutcome)
        Catch ex As Exception
            Dim split As String() = ex.Message.Split(New String() {"ORA-06512:"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
            vOutcome = split(0)
            lsDisplay.Items.Add(vOutcome)
        Finally
        End Try
    End Sub
```

This is the CUSTOMER table definition

```
CREATE TABLE "S5849497"."CUSTOMER" 
   (    "CUSTID" NUMBER, 
    "CUSTNAME" VARCHAR2(100 BYTE), 
    "SALES_YTD" NUMBER, 
    "STATUS" VARCHAR2(7 BYTE), 
     PRIMARY KEY ("CUSTID")
  USING INDEX PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 COMPUTE STATISTICS 
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "USERS"  ENABLE, 
     CONSTRAINT "CK_ID_RANGE" CHECK (custid > 0 and custid < 500) ENABLE
   ) SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE 
  PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 NOCOMPRESS LOGGING
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "USERS" ;
```

Comment: That's a method not a function. You should keep your database calls seperate that way you can call the function to get the data you need and then put it where you need it.

Comment: Please edit your question and include the definition of the CUSTOMER table. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The return value string size needed to be set to a higher value. I set it to 4000 just to be safe but by default it must be set to a much lower value. This fixed the issue right away

```
param.size = 4000
```